# Displaying result of AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have looked far and wide how to do the below, but I have come up short, and am struggling to actually find a resource that explains **ajax** and how it works.

I have sent through a ajax request to a `php` file from the below code, and using the network tab in `mozillas developer console`, I see that it does get the response code (which is echo'd out info inside HTML elements)

Although I can see the response, I don't know how to display it, using the below code (which I've compiled after looking through numerous similar questions on stack overflow). Please could someone have a look and see why this is not displaying?

```
<div id='picoutput'></div>
<script>


        $.ajax({
        url: 'resources/listposts.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: \"json\",
        data: {
            uname: $('$uname').val(),
        },

          success:function(data) {
            if(data) {   // DO SOMETHING     
                $('#picoutput').html(data).value;
            } else { // DO SOMETHING }
          }
        }
       });


</script>
```

The response is

```
<div id='post'><div id='postleft' style='float:left;clear:left;width: 15%;'>
    <div id='profilepic2'>
       <img src='../uploads/default1562925803.jpg' id='profilepic'>
    </div>
    <h4 style='margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;;color:grey'>Dowayne Breedt<br>Support<br>2016-05-24</h><br>
</div>
<div id='postright'style='width: 82%;float:right; padding:     10px;background-color:white;height:inherit'>
    <h2>...</h2>
    <p>only refresh if extend is off<br />
    </p>
    </div>  
    </div>"
```

Comment: Please show your response and what you want to display?

Comment: Are you returning json from PHP? if so use the index to display `$('#picoutput').html(data.id)`

Comment: Hey!, The below is the response the browser gets(there are a few but I have only included one), I would like it to display these posts within the picoutput  -- Edit : I will include the response in the original post

Comment: @DowayneBreedt can you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: try document.getElementById('picoutput').innerHTML = data.value and before that try - $('#picoutput').html(data.value);

Comment: show the json response.question is very unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for helping out, its been a cool first experience and I;m glad there are people who are willing to assist a beginner.

I was being silly with this, it turned out, all that needed to be done, was to change the data type from JSON to html, once that was done, it loaded perfectly.

Again, thank you for trying to assist.

Answer (score 1):

Put this and see what 'data' object is including. Check it by using firebug etc then use it.

```
success:function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $('#picoutput').val(data.id); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In ajax success response inside the parenthesis you get the success response from the page and to use that success response you can do something like below

for setting value of success response in some input type

```
success:function(data) {
            if(data) {   // DO SOMETHING     
                $('#picoutput').val(data);// input's id('#picoutput') + val() is using here for setting the value in some input type 
            } else { // DO SOMETHING }
          }
        }
```

for showing some result inside html div or something like that you can do something like below

```
success:function(data) {
            if(data) {   // DO SOMETHING     
                $('#picoutput').html(data); //html div's id('#picoutput')+html() no need for value or val()
            } else { // DO SOMETHING }
          }
        }
```

hope it will help you and others also ..